# How to remove an undefined value of a dynamic array

Tags: javascript

I have an array that adds values dynamically but sometimes returns `undefined` as a value, I want to know how can I remove all the undefined values.

This is my code:

```
var arr =[//Values]

let forDeletion = [undefined]
arr = arr.filter(item => !forDeletion.includes(item))
```

But obviusly this is not working

Comment: Without knowing what `arr` contains and what your expected output is, does `arr.filter(item => item !== undefined)` work?

Comment: your code appears to work....

Comment: Below link has the solution for your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
let forDeletion = [1,undefined, null, 'a']

let arr = forDeletion.filter(x=> x!==undefined )

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @TylerRoper OP use `includes` function

Comment: Well yes, but what does your code do differently? What was OP's question that you're answering?

Comment: I understand that OP ask about the way of filter out `undefined` values

Comment: The problem is that OP's code works fine, so even if this *does* work for OP, it provides nothing to future readers. It doesn't explain what was wrong (*which, again, there is nothing wrong*), doesn't explain why this is a solution, etc. I agree that it's a better *alternative* to OP's code, but I just don't see how it's an "answer". Perhaps it should be a comment.

Comment: @TylerRoper - I test OP code and it works wrong - delete all items

Comment: Using the example array from your answer, [OP's code produces the same exact output](https://jsfiddle.net/nz4fhvpL/).

Comment: @TylerRoper yes you are right - I don see that he use filter on `arr` not forDeletion - however (he's code looks wired) - however he write that his code not works - so may be he make mistake writing code in question?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arra1=["aa",1,2,undefined,true,null]
console.log(arra1.filter(element=>element !==undefined))
```