# Cannot filter empty element from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with this piece of code.

I import input data from a file formated like so and store it in `const input`:

```
aabcccccaaa
aaccb
shsudbud
```

There are no spaces or any other white characters except from '\n' newline.

I get inputs in this way: (LiveServer inside VS Code)

```
const getData = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch("./inputs.txt");
  const data = await resp.text();
  return data;
};
```

Then I call:

```
const myFunc = async () => {
  const input = await getData();
  const rows = input.split("\n").map(row => row);
  rows.forEach(row => {
    const charArr = [...row];
    console.log(charArr);
  });
};
```

After logging to console first and second row it seems like there is "" (empty string) attached to the end of each of them. The third element is fine so I guess its somehow connected with newline character.

I have also tried creating charArr by doing:

```
const charArr = Array.from(row);
```

Or

```
const charArr = row.split("");
```

But the outcome was the same.

Later I found this topic: [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

So I tried:

```
const charArr = [...row].filter(Boolean);
```

But the "" is still at the end of charArr created from 1st and 2nd row.

```js
const input = `aabcccccaaa
aaccb
shsudbud`;

const rows = input.split("\n").map(row => row);
rows.forEach(row => {
  const charArr = [...row];
  console.log(charArr);
});
```

In this snippet everything works fine. So here is where my questions start:

1. Why does .filter() method not work properly in this case?
2. Could this problem browser specific?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `trim()` ... `const rows = input.split("\n").map(row => row.trim());`. Not really clear if you are getting empty element(s) in array....or space at end of characters within rows

Comment: Maybe do a `console.log(btoa(await getData()))` and tell us what is printed.