# How to remove different types of empty values (elements) from JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, is-empty

Have an array

```
const arr = [1, 'abc', [], ['John'], {}, {name: 'Smith'}, null, 0];
```

How to get new array without empty values?
(empty array and empty object are also reckoned as empty values).

My variant seems to be a bit of hardcoded:

```
const newArr = arr.filter(elem => 
            (elem && Object.keys(elem).length !== 0) 
            || (typeof(elem) == 'number' && elem !== 0));
```

If is it possible to write less or simplier conditions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript) Probably this question has similar solutions, I would take a look.

Comment: `!= null`, but it takes all falsy values, like false and {}

Comment: If you are using *lodash* library, there is already a utility [isEmpty](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEmpty) for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *falsy* values, empty object and array you have to use this part:

```
elem && Object.keys(elem).length !== 0
```

But you can minimise it like:

```
elem && Object.keys(elem).length
```

as any value for `length` > 0 will return as *truthy*.

Also, you can minimise the number logic like:

```
arr.filter(elem => Number(elem));
```

So, the final version will be like:

```js
const arr = [1, 'abc', [], ['John'], {}, {name: 'Smith'}, null, 0];
const newArr = arr.filter(a => (a && Object.keys(a).length) || Number(a));
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work. And advice to minimise was pretty reasonable

Comment: I believe 0 should be included in the result as 'non-empty' value. Above code excludes that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have specific variants you can try

```
const emptyVariants = ['', 0, null,] // all expected variants
const newArr = arr.filter(elem => !emptyVariants.includes(elem);
```

Another approach that you can try is using `!=` but it takes all falsy values

```
const newArr = arr.filter(elem => (elem != null));
```

For more information see `!=` and `==` operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Only `emptyVariants[1]` contains that specific empty object, most likely that same object doesn't occur anywhere else. Also detecting `null` seems to fail ...

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
 arr.filter(i => (typeof i === 'number') || (i && i.length>0) || (( i && Object.keys(i).length)>0) || (i===0));
```