# Async useState leading to undefined element down the hierarchy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

### Setup/Scenario

I am using twitter api to fetch data and rendering it in twitter card using [react-native-socials](https://github.com/PierreCapo/react-native-socials).
The tweet data ( JSON ) is stored and served through my backend and rendered in the app.

I am using a Flatlist to render this data.

### Problem

[image]
It's working fine for the first 3 loads, I am using `pullToRefresh` in `flatlist` to do a network call to get new data.

But when I try the 4th time it gets an `undefined` element.

I've replaced the `Twitter` element ( from react-native-socials lib ) with a `Text` element, then there's no `undefined` in the output and it doesn't crash.

This `undefined` is what's causing the element to crash at a place where it's trying to get a particular key from the json data being passed to the `Twitter` element.

More importantly I tried logging it up the chain but in vain. I had to go inside the library and add `console.log` just where the object was being destructured and assigned.

#### Relevant Code

- The flatlist component

```js
<FlatList
      ref={refContainer}
      data={feed}
      keyExtractor={(post) => {
        return post.id.toString();
      }}
      ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderComponent}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View
          style={{
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 35,
            backgroundColor: colors.white,
          }}
        >
          {item && item.type == postType.TWEET && (
            <Twitter useCustomTweetExtendedData={item.content} />
          )}
```

- Code from the library : `node_modules/react-native-socials/dist/src/Twitter/api.js`
  It errors out in `data.created_at` and hence I added a `console.log`

```js
export var adapter = function (data) {
  console.log("typeof : "+ typeof(data) + " full_text : " + entities.decode(data?.full_text.slice(0, 10)));
  var _a, _b, _c, _d, _e, _f;
  var response = {
    createdAt: data.created_at,
    id: data.id,
```

### Things I've already tried out :

1. Supplying a default value - Did that still the error occurs
2. `useEffect` for `feed` - Can't do this as the first time `loadFeed` is called to set the `feed`

Some of the articles I referred before asking here :

1. [This discusses quite a few strategies](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-usestate-hook-guide/)

### Questions

1. Why the error only happens in the 3rd network call ( yes it's consistent ) ? - There's enough data to fetch for atleast 10 such calls
2. Why isn't it logged in up the chain ?
3. I've put checks like this one : `{item && item.type == postType.TWEET &&`  and yet how come it goes down to the component and creates an error ?
4. How do I solve this

I read [this - useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877875) but didn't understand how I could use this to solve my problem.

Thanks a lot.

### Update

On suggestion on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/j53i3o/async_usestate_leading_to_undefined_element_down/g7rc5jg?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) I added a [null rejector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281335/11857690) kind of thing `data.filter(obj => obj)` but that doesn't seem to help either :/

I am using flatlist to render a full array of objects, fetched from a backend server.

I checked the data using Postman, it was coming fine, no null values there.

Here's my `feed` loading code.

```js
const loadFeed = async (typeOfFeed, old = false) => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    let url = "";
    if (old) {
        url = FeedCursor.next;
    }
    const response = await postsApi.getPosts(typeOfFeed, url);
    if (response.ok) {
      if (response.data[0].id == feed[0]?.id) {
        ToastAndroid.show("No new posts", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      } else if (response.data.length > 0) {
          setFeedCursor({
            next: response.headers.next,
            previous: response.headers.previous,
          });
        }
        response.data.filter((obj) => obj);    // Updated this
        setFeed(response.data);
      }
    } else {
      ToastAndroid.show("No new posts", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      console.error(response.problem);
    }
    setRefreshing(false);
  };
```

Another thing is that before this happens, on a previous load it mentions that :

```sh
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```