# How to avoid empty objects in array from string separated by comma using JavaScript and NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have an input in which I can type tags separated by comma. Said input can receive a string in this way:

```
hola, hello, hola hello, , hola,
```

The string is then sent to the backend of my app in this way:

```
req.body.tags.split(',').map((tag) => tag.trim())
```

This only helps to split the string by commas

```
string1, string2
```

That's great but what if I had a string as the one shown below:

```
string1, string2, , string4
```

How can I ignore or remove the empty 'object' between the commas after string2 and the comma after string4?. Not only that, what if I had a string that looks similar to the first one I mentioned before?

```
string1, string2, , string4, string5,
```

Let's not forget about the spaces(which I would like to replace with a hyphen):

```
string1, string2, , string4, string 5, string6,
```

How would I ignore the empty object after the last comma also?

I'm asking because this is how it usually looks on my mongoDB after the data is sent:

```
tags: [
  "string1",
  "string2",
  "",
  "string4",
  "string5",
  ""
]
```

I'm just trying to avoid having empty objects.

UPDATE ONE:

```
req.body.tags.split(',').map((tag) => tag.trim()).filter((tag) => tag.length !== 0)
```

It works great. With that being said, I still need to replace the spaces with hyphens. I tried this and did not work:

```
req.body.tags
          .split(',')
          .map((tag) =>
            tag
              .trim()
              .replace(/[\s]+/g, '-')
              .toLowerCase()
          )
          .filter((tag) => tag.length !== 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` function to remove empty strings from array.

```js
const tags = 'hola, hello, hola hello, , hola,';
const res = tags
  .split(',')
  .map((tag) => tag.trim())
  .filter((tag) => tag.length !== 0);
console.log(res);
```

If you want to replace all spaces from the string item of the array, you can do it as below.

```js
const tags = 'h o la, hello, hola hello, , hola,';
const res = tags
  .split(',')
  .map((tag) => tag.trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, '-').toLowerCase())
  .filter((tag) => tag.length !== 0);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you sir for this!. If you don't mind, do you have any idea on how replace the spaces found within a single object from the array?

I tried this but did not work:
`req.body.tags
          .split(',')
          .map((tag) =>
            tag
              .trim()
              .replace(/[\s]+/g, '-')
              .toLowerCase()
          )
          .filter((tag) => tag.length !== 0)`

Comment: @Kirasiris Is this result you want? `'ho la, hello, hola hello, , hola,'` => `[ 'ho-la', 'hello', 'hola-hello', 'hola' ]`

Comment: I think your code (in the comment) works fine. let me try and update it on my answer

Comment: It did not work on my end first, then I had to restart the server and it suddenly worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array for empty characters to prevent this.

```js
var sparseArray = [0, , , 1, , , , , 2, , , , 3],
cleanArray = sparseArray.filter(function () { return true });
console.log(cleanArray); // [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

see full post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)