# Delete an attribute in an array of JSON objects oin typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have an array of data. What I want to do is to delete the attribute from the objects where it is null, like in case of the 3rd object I want to delete the img attribute. What I have tried so far is

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'name1',
    img: 'car1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name2',
    img: 'car2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'name3',
    img: null
  }
]
data.forEach(function(value) {
  for (var key in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var val = value[key];
      if (val == null) {
        delete data[value[key]];
      }
    }
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

But the deletion is not happening, any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `delete value[key];` ... The deletion is from the object, not from the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: No It does not. The below one seems to work for me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'name1',
    img: 'car1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name2',
    img: 'car2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'name3',
    img: null
  }
]

data.forEach(d => {
  Object.keys(d).forEach(key => {
    if (d[key] == null) delete d[key];
  });
});

console.log(data);
```