# How to ignore empty string in list object?

Tags: javascript

I have list object like below

```
0:""
1:""
3:"tag1"
4:"tag2
```

This is my question how to ignore empty value.I need a result like the  below.

```
0:"tag1"
1:"tag2
```

Thanks for help me.

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` to return just the non-empty strings.

Comment: What you've shared does not look like an object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

One naive solution could be:

```js
const obj = {
  0: "",
  1: "",
  2: "tag1",
  3: "tag2"
};

const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => v)
);
```

`Object.entries` turns an object into an array of keys and values.

For example

```
Object.entries(obj)
```

becomes

```
[
  [
    "0",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "1",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "2",
    "tag1"
  ],
  [
    "3",
    "tag2"
  ]
]
```

which is then filtered by whether the value is "truthy"

```
.filter(([k,v]) => v))
```

and finally turned back into an object

```
Object.fromEntries
```

Comment: did you mean native or naive?

Comment: @Kinglish definitely naive. My answer isn't super comprehensive, and does not take edge-cases into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

If that is an array, you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
let o = ["","",,"tag1","tag2"];
let res = o.filter(Boolean); // or o.filter(x => x);
console.log(res);
```

To be more precise, you could use:

```
let res = o.filter(x => x !== '');
```