# codewars Array.diff javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

this is my first question as I'm learning programming for few days but now and I'm stuck

Task:

> Your goal in this kata is to implement a difference function, which subtracts one list from another and returns the result.
>
> It should remove all values from list `a`, which are present in list `b` keeping their order.
>
> `arrayDiff([1,2],[1]) == [2]`
> If a value is present in `b`, all of its occurrences must be removed from the other:
>
> `arrayDiff([1,2,2,2,3],[2]) == [1,3]`

My solution:

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {  
for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if(a[j] == b[i]) {
      a.splice(j);
      j--;
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

Looks like I'm doing something wrong and peculiar thing happens:
sometimes tests turn all red, sometimes all BUT 1 test turn red, while rest is green.
The one that always fails me is:

Should pass Basic tests

`a` was `[1,2]`, `b` was `[1]`: expected `[]` to deeply equal `[ 2 ]`

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) of `.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, itemN)`, escpecially what `deleteCount` is for and the behavior when its missing.

Comment: 'I'm learning programming for few days' and then you use the phrase 'to deeply equal'. It seems you have a very fast brain. I would like to deeply equal it.

Comment: @JoePythonKing that's just what the test says ^^ I don't undesrstand the concept of 'deeply equal' myself

Comment: lots of good stuff on this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Did my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68994262/13833218) solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your function is, that you change the length of your a array while in a for loop, which uses the length of a. This causes certain index to be skipped.

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {  
for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if(a[j] == b[i]) {
      // here you change the size of a.
      a.splice(j);
      j--;
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

To fix this, create a temporary array, in which you push all values from a, which are not contained in b.

```
function arrayDiff(a,b) {
    // Temporary array, containing all values from a, which are not contained in b
    let diffArray = [];
    // Looping over a
    for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // Per default we say that b does not contain a
        let bContainsAValue = false;
        // Loop over b
        for(let y = 0; y < b.length; y++) {
            // If any value in b is the same as the current value from a, we set bContainsAValue to true
            if(a[i] === b[y]) bContainsAValue = true;
        }
        // Now only if bContainsAValue is still false, meaning it does not contain the a value, we push this value into our temporary array
        if(!bContainsAValue) diffArray.push(a[i]);
    }
    // In the end we return the temporary array
    return diffArray;
}
```

Here is my approach, which is simpler and uses some array functions:

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
    // Filter entire a array, only keep the value if b does not contain that value
    return a.filter(val => !b.includes(val));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input @Andreas, I've changed my answer!
Let me know if this is fine.

Comment: Thank you @Flashtube I see now that creating a new array is a good solution. I thought that my "j--" will work the same way, apparently it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy approach that you can take to solve the error in your code with a mix of [ES6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp).

Since your array length changes over the loop, you can use `delete array[j]` to remove the value without changing the length of the array or the index of elements. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767335/13833218)

> If you just want to make the element at index `i` no longer exist, but
> you don't want the indexes of the other elements to change:

This replaces the duplicate values with `undefined`. Then you can remove all the `undefined` elements with a single line

```
a.filter(Boolean)
```

[Refer more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843625/13833218)

```js
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      if (a[j] == b[i]) {
        delete a[j];
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(a.filter(Boolean))
  return a.filter(Boolean);
}
arrayDiff([1, 2], [1])
arrayDiff([1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2])
```

Here's a single liner using ES6 without any nesting or mutation

```js
const arrayDiff = (a, b) => a.filter(item => !b.includes(item))
console.log(arrayDiff([1, 2], [1]))
console.log(arrayDiff([1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2]))
```

Comment: This answer does not work!
If you try this function with arrayDiff([1,2,2,2,3], [2]) it should remove all 2 from the a array, but the result is
[1, 2, 3]

Comment: I'll check it out!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the builtin methods for array, and combine that with the set. Something like the following:

```
function diff(a, b) {
  const left = a.filter(item => !b.includes(item))
  const right = b.filter(item => !a.includes(item))
  return Array.from(new Set([].concat(left, right)))
}
```

By your example

```
diff([1,2,2,2,3],[2]) // returns [1, 3]
diff([1,2],[1]) // returns [2]
```

The function should also be transitive, I.e the parameter order should not matter when calculating a difference. So flipping the parameters should return the same result.

```
diff([2], [1,2,2,2,3]) // returns [1, 3]
diff([1],[1,2]) // returns [2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```html
#  create a function, pass in the listNames as parameters
def array_diff(a, b):
    # create an entity removeNum: the loop through b, to check if it's in list b
    for removeNumber in b:
    #  If removeNum is in b, loop through a as well to check if it's there
        while removeNumber in a:
    #  So, if removeNum is in list a
            try:
    #  Try function to remove it from a... using .remove()
                a.remove(removeNumber)
    #  except to return empty list
            except ValueError:
                return[]
    return a
```