# How can I get the number of characters in a line in a template literal?

Tags: javascript, string, slice, template-literals

I have a multi-line template literal. I want to splice it based on line number and character index in the line. For that, I need the number of characters in a given line. How can I get this number?

As for what I have tried, well, I pretty much only put random numbers into `slice()` to see how much it slices.

Thanks.

Comment: [`how-to-ask`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  What have you tried?

Comment: Just split into lines, take the one you want, slice that by index?

Comment: Thank you @Bergi! Sorry, I just have some thing to learn when it comes to strings ^^

Answer (score 1):

`split()` on `\n` to get each line.
`filter()` on `True` value to remove the empty indexes.

Now you can use `.length` on the desired index to get the length of that line:

```js
const templateLiteral = `
Hello
FooBar
Something else on this line
123456789
`;

const lines = templateLiteral.split("\n").filter(v => v);

for (let i in lines) {
    console.log(`Line ${+i + 1} has: ${lines[i].length} chars`);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `v => v` mean? I assume it is a lambda function...

Comment: It's a short way of [removing all empty strings from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
let text =
  `The quick
brown fox
jumps over
the lazy dog`;
let res = text.split('\n');
res.forEach((element, index)=>{
  console.log(`Line no:${index+1}   ${element}     length: ${element.length}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I used `split()`, then sliced the element in the array corresponding to the line I want. Example:

```js
var text = `As the trees grow
I'm starting to know
That I love you`;

var splitText = text.split("\n");
var slice = splitText[1].slice(4, 15);
console.log(slice); // starting to
```