# How to split string into parts using Regex

Tags: regex, split, match

I have a string containing placeholders which I want replace with other strings, but I would also like to split the string whenever I encounter a placeholder.

So, by splitting I mean that

```
"This {0} is an example {1} with a placeholder"
```

should become:

```
parts[0] -> "This"
parts[1] -> "{0}"
parts[2] -> "is an example"
parts[3] -> "{1}"
parts[4] -> "with a placeholder"
```

and then the next step would be to replace the placeholders (this part is simple):

```
parts[0] -> "This"
parts[1] -> value[0]
parts[2] -> "is an example"
parts[3] -> value[1]
parts[4] -> "with a placeholder"
```

I know how to match and replace the placeholders (e.g. `({\d+})`), but no clue how to tell regex to "match non placeholders" and "match placeholders" at the same time.

My idea was something like: `(?!{\d+})+ | ({\d+})` but it's not working. I am doing this in JavaScript if Regex flavor is important.

If I can also replace the placeholders with a value in one step it would be neat, but I can also do this after I split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might write the pattern as:

```
{\d+}|\S.*?(?=\s*(?:{\d+}|$))
```

The pattern matches:

- `{\d+}` Match `{` 1+ digits and `}`
- `|` Or
- `\S.*?` Match a non whitespace char followed by any character as few as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
  - `(?:{\d+}|$)` Match either `{` 1+ digits and `}` or assert the end of the string
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ua7UZu/1)

To get an array with those values:

```js
const regex = /{\d+}|\S.*?(?=\s*(?:{\d+}|$))/gm;
const str = `This {0} is an example {1} with a placeholder`;
console.log(str.match(regex))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you [use parenthesis around the separator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?retiredLocale=en#splitting_with_a_regexp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result), *matched results are included* in the output:

```
let parts = str.split(/ *({\d+}) */);
```

[See this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##HYwxDsIwDAD3vsJbkyJa2JAqfsHIYqUWCTJNFFsFqcrbQ2C65e6euKG4HJIet0utTAqiGa7Q33wQ2E8FGnAF@uArMcF@LvAO6gEhMTrykRfK/dx1vzZhVml1e4ySOKiZYDD7fTkUC8Nkm@biKpFp5Pgwf93OtX4B) - If separator occurs at start/end, just [filter out empty matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript).

---

If your goal is just to replace, it can be done in one step using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a callback:

```
str = str.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, (m0, m1) => value[m1]);
```

[Another demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##Jcy9DoIwFIbhvVdxtrYR@dlMCFyFGzIc4QiYlpK2ognh2muV5fum533iiq6z0@LP6yUERR6ct1ABv46Tgy3fIR7OQB/UiyLYih3ekx8BYVHY0WhUT5aXjP3siupFUTf8YQxP@B0tbxk7knFTS38lsk3c@pPcsyEBofMEdCGhqo9Ao4tWxmJnZmcUpcoMImJZhvAF) - `m0` is the full match, `m1` holds the [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) of the *first group*.
Used with [`g` *(global)* flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) to return all possible matches in the string (not just the first).