# Need code to count only not-empty rows in html table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, rowcount

I have a javascript code to count records in html table, but it counts all and I need to count not empty only:
If I click the button it shows 5 rows, but I need to make count equal to 4.
Need java-script code to skip empty rows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
         var rowCount = $("#myTable tr").length;
         alert(rowCount); // Outputs: 4
     });
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="myTable" border="1" width="140">
     <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>25</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td>18</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Harry</td>
            <td>14</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
   <br>
  <button type="button">Get Number of Rows</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Seems what u need is just filter out the empty rows that is getting saved in rowcount. May be this code can help.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
         var rowCount = $("#myTable tr");
         //\t\t indecates that the row is empty
         var filteredRowCount = $.grep(rowCount, n => n.innerText!="\t\t" );
         alert(filteredRowCount.length); // Outputs: 4
     });
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="myTable" border="1" width="140">
     <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>25</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td>18</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Harry</td>
            <td>14</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
   <br>
  <button type="button">Get Number of Rows</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript) to find more ways to filter the array